# What to do about mistaken copyediting if reverting a bad reversion gets rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, grammar

What can be done if a well-meaning but misinformed editor changes a question away from standard English and attempts to fix it are rejected as  "completely superfluous"?

**Example**

This example will be easier to understand if you are familiar with standard English usage of the adjective *everyday*. See [here](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/everyday-vs-every-day/).

Here is the edit history in question: [history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/145087/edit).

Chronology:

- Original author included nonstandard usage.
- On Sep 19, 16:51 CDT, another author corrected this usage.
- At the same date and time, another author decided to "correct" the correction by reverting it to nonstandard usage.
- I attempted to restore the appropriate correction. Of course I had to make other changes for no reason other than to get to six characters.
- My edit was rejected because "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

That's erroneous. My edit changed it back to standard English. Standard English is patently more accurate than nonstandard in professional settings such as a Q&A site.

Assuming it's a policy of 
StackExchange that standard written English is preferable to nonstandard, there is probably some process to get this reviewed and fixed. What is that process?

Comment: I'll address one objection: 
"A majority of English speakers don't even know about the difference, so why do you even care?"

1. Broken windows theory -- largely debunked in criminology, but still valid in other areas.

Comment: Like it or not, *everyday* is used by many people in modern English to mean *every day*. To say that it's simply wrong is misleading. It's a matter of choice if somebody wants to spell it as a single word. Personally, I  don't like it. But it's up to the author.

Comment: Wait till you get full editing privileges, then you don't have to worry about reviewers. Also to reviewers, who might not see the same importance of the change as you see, might definitely side with superfluous. That's the drawback when suggesting edits rather then making edits. Also it would be best to revert the latest reversal, rather then editing.

Comment: @JasonBassford So is any prescriptive grammar appropriate? E.g. possessive *it's* is widely recognized by most educated users of English as nonstandard, despite being widespread. Is it desirable for editors to install this usage and make it very hard (maybe impossible for me) to revert? I'd argue that reflects poorly on the site.

Comment: @Luuklag: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware there was an option to revert the latest reversal. I searched the page for the string "revert" but didn't find anything. Do you happen to know what it's called?

Comment: @CynicallyNaive its called Rollback

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks. Unfortunately my search for "rollback" on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/145087/edit also turns up nothing. Is this feature only available to a subset of users?

Comment: You would need 2k rep. Or be post owner I think

Comment: So, summarizing: Editors can replace "correct" (standard) English with incorrect at will. New-to-that-SE users can't revert such edits atomically, and adding additional dummy edits is also frowned upon. This reminds me of past days of Wikipedia where persistent malicious editors would win in conflict. Seems like an extremely broken model. This use case may be tiny, but the principle is no different with any grammar of which the reviewers are unaware.